# Allowing XMPP users to change passwords against prosody

Tags: passwords, xmpp, prosody-im

I have a running prosody that handles XMPP for a couple of my domains, and a friends domain. One of the users (his wife) on my friend's domain would like to change her password (actually she has forgotten her, so I would set one with prosodyctl that she should then change to something I don't know). But when I try changing the password of a test user I created on that domain through pidgin, I get an error saying "Error changing password", "Service unavailable". What do I need to change to allow users to change passwords?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the needed clue in [The ArchLinux wiki on prosody](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Prosody), even though it claims it to be the default (it might be on Arch, it wasn't on my Debian), I needed to enable the `register` module, and make sure `allow_registration` was set to `false`.